How to get data from NSE using Python
I am trying to get data (file) from NSE website. Recently, NSE changed the data format and switched to UDiFF format. But since then, the below sample code has not worked. Can anybody give some thoughts on this.
import json
import requests

csvfile = 'BhavCopy_NSE_CM_0_0_0_20240712_F_0000.csv.zip'

try:
    print(f'Downloading {csvfile} from NSE')
    url = 'https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/cm/BhavCopy_NSE_CM_0_0_0_20240712_F_0000.csv.zip'
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
        print(chunk)
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Could not download {csvfile} from NSE')

When the above code is executed, it just awaits a response from NSE forever. There is no error or warning, or timeout being observed.

The problem is not with Python.  wget and curl can't download this URL either, with the same symptoms.  You'll have to investigate if it's posible to workaround it with using additional HTTP headers from the subset sent by browser.  Likely candidates include User-Agent, Referer, Content-Type, and cookies.

Just add headers and it should work.
import json
import requests

csvfile = 'BhavCopy_NSE_CM_0_0_0_20240712_F_0000.csv.zip'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
}

try:
    print(f'Downloading {csvfile} from NSE')
    url = 'https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/cm/BhavCopy_NSE_CM_0_0_0_20240712_F_0000.csv.zip'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
    # for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
    #     print(chunk) it is a zip file so why do you want to print binary data?
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Could not download {csvfile} from NSE')


Thanks for your post. I was trying to get it worked on aws but it did not succeed (sorry I did not mention aws env in my question). So I tried the below code and it works as on today :)
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/cm/BhavCopy_NSE_CM_0_0_0_20240712_F_0000.csv.zip"
    print("Downloading: BhavCopy_NSE_CM_0_0_0_20240712_F_0000.csv.zip")
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Test App/1.0 (Language=python/3.7)',
        'Accept-Language': '*'
    }
                    
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(r)    


So... Pretty much what Nesi suggested?
